# Render controls dynamically

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I have a component that dynamically renders Ionic components:

```
<div *ngIf="property && property.type === 'data'">

  <div *ngIf="property.controlType === 'label'">
    <ion-label>{{data}}</ion-label>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="property.controlType === 'date'">
    <ion-label>{{ toDate(data) }}</ion-label>
  </div>

</div>
```

The result is something like:

```
<div>
  <div>
     <ion-label>Hello World</ion-label>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I need just the ionic component, without the divs:

```
<ion-label>Hello World</ion-label>
```

How can I achieve this with lowest redundancy?

Edit:
I don't want something like:

```
<ion-label *ngIf="property && property.type === 'data' && property.controlType === 'label'">{{data}}</ion-label>
<ion-label *ngIf="property && property.type === 'data' && property.controlType === 'date'">{{data}}</ion-label>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `*ngIf` directly on the `ion-label`

```html
<ion-label *ngIf="property?.type === 'metaData' && property?.controlType === 'date'">{{ toDate(data) }}</ion-label>
```

EDIT:

Otherwise you can create these checks inside the component class and apply these values to boolean properties like `isDate` or `isLabel`.

Then you can do

```html
 <ion-label *ngIf="isDate">{{ toDate(data) }}<ion-label>
 <ion-label *ngIf="isLabel">{{ toDate(data) }}<ion-label>
```

Otherwise you can use `ng-container` which does not add extra-levels of html in the build files, like the `div` does. In combination with switchCase you would end up like:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="properties?.type === 'metaData'>
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="properties?.controlType">
    <ion-label *ngSwitchCase="date">...</ion-label>
    <ion-label *ngSwitchCase="lavel">...</ion-label>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This would result in a lot of same code (see my last comment in the question)

Comment: Updated my answer with two different approaches